# understanding unapply without case class

Tags: scala, unapply

I am trying out below example to understand `unapply`,

```
class Emp(name: String, age: Int)

object Emp {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Emp = new Emp(name, age)

  def unapply(emp: Emp): Option[(String, Int)] = Some(emp.name, emp.age)
}
```

Unfortunately, it fails with compilation error `Cannot resolve symbol name`, `Cannot resolve symbol age`.

Whereas, when i declare `Emp` as `case` class, it works prefectly fine without any compilation error.

Can someone please explain reason behind this?

Note: scalaVersion- 2.12.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error tell you, that scala can't see the properties in class `Emp`. in order to expose them, you need smth like this (more on this in [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-visibility-constructor-fields-scala-val-var-private)):

```
class Emp(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

moreover, `Some` accepts only one argument, so you need to return a pair:

```
Some((emp.name, emp.age))
```

Comment: Right... need to declare it with `val` to expose it outside class.

Comment: @Mukeshprajapati Scala classes behave like Java classes, in that they require getters and setters in order to access their parameters. Declaring them as `val` seems to bypass this, as does declaring the class as a `case class`.